Unable to display image in header component after deploying to gh-pages. 404 not found error message
export default function Header() {
    return (
        <header className="header">
            <img 
                src="troll-face.png" 
                className="header--image"
            />
            <h2 className="header--title">Meme Generator</h2>
            <h4 className="header--project">React Course - Project 3</h4>
        </header>
    )
}


I have tried creating different folders for images, i have tried putting the image in an assets folder, public folder, main folder. Nothing that I do is working. I have also tried removing the ./ or the / or putting ../. It still isn't showing up

I tried making the path of the image different several different ways by putting dots and forward slashes. so far nothing has worked. I am using vite and react.
